# Is Crypt32.lib FIPS 140-2 compliant?

Tags: cryptography, crypt, fips

We are using the api CryptProtectData and CryptUnprotectData from the Crypt32.lib for encryption and decryption in our C++ application.

Is this lib and the Api FIPS 140-2 compliant?

Comment: There is two levels of being FIPS compliant: you can either write a library to be compatible with the NISt & FIPS recommendations or you can go through the validation program and be officially compliant. In the latter case you have an option to be listed bij NIST.